# Installing Orchard using existing database

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have installed orchard using an existing database which already contains lot of content definition. One of the content looks as follows in the admin dashboard
[image]

but when i try to view the content from front end site using `http://localhost:30320/orchardlocal/award-winners`, the content does not show up. I rather get a not found page from Orchard.

Can anybody tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the error logs. And I'm not sure if OrchardLocal needs to be the correct case? Probably not but you can try :)

Comment: ?That content item is published? Just checking.

Comment: Is the site even configured on localhost:30320, or is that just the base URL that's configured in settings?

Comment: localhost:30320/orchardLocal is the baseURL when I run the orchard from visual studio 2012. Its not configured anywhere. Where can I check the configuration? Where I can see the error logs?

Comment: If I unpublish and again publish the content, it starts showing in the front website. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by Unpublishing all content and then again publishing it